# "Correlated column is not allowed in predicate" in SparkSQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks, predicate

I'm running into an issue migrating a SQL Stored Procedure to SparkSQL. I am getting this error in Databricks:

> Correlated column is not allowed in predicate

I have the following type of query:

```sql
WITH CTE_1
AS (
     SELECT id, Date, ......
     FROM table
   ),
CTE_2
AS (
     SELECT Date, SUM(blablabla) AS SUM 
     FROM CTE_1
     WHERE (SELECT  COUNT(1)
            FROM    CTE_1 AS prev
            WHERE   MONTHS_BETWEEN(LEFT(prev.Date,7), LEFT(CTE_1.Date,7)) = 1
            AND     CTE_1.id = PREV.id
            ) = 0
     AND CTE_1.Date != (SELECT MIN(Date) FROM CTE_1)
     GROUP BY Date
)

SELECT *
FROM CTE_2
```

What would be the best way to set this up in SparkSQL?

Comment: Hi @JVGBI, could you please edit the question to add your sample data and the error you are getting?

Comment: Added the error, sample data would be too hard. I'm hoping someone can see the construction with the subquery and knows to to efficiently do this in SparkSQL

Comment: Ranking functions like ROW_NUMBER and RANK often provide solutions to issues like this.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you effectively make a loop: for every id, you compare every Date with every other Date of CTE_1.

You should be able to rewrite it to use window functions.

I tried to do it, but without example data, I'm not sure I understood it correctly. This is what I came up with:

```sql
WITH CTE_1
AS (
    SELECT id, Date, blablabla, LEAD(Date) OVER (partition by id order by Date) AS Lead
    FROM table
),
CTE_2
AS (
    SELECT Date, SUM(blablabla) AS SUM 
    FROM CTE_1
    WHERE MONTHS_BETWEEN(LEFT(Lead,7), LEFT(Date,7)) != 1
       OR Lead is null
    GROUP BY Date
)

SELECT *
FROM CTE_2
```

Testing in PySpark:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("1", '2022-01-07', 5),
     ("1", '2022-02-07', 5),
     ("1", '2022-03-07', 5),
     ("1", '2022-07-07', 5),
     ("2", '2022-06-07', 5),
     ("2", '2022-07-07', 5),
     ("3", '2022-07-07', 5)],
    ["id", "Date", "blablabla"])
df.createOrReplaceTempView("table")

spark.sql(
    """
    WITH CTE_1
    AS (
        SELECT id, Date, blablabla, LEAD(Date) OVER (partition by id order by Date) AS Lead
        FROM table
    ),
    CTE_2
    AS (
        SELECT Date, SUM(blablabla) AS SUM 
        FROM CTE_1
        WHERE MONTHS_BETWEEN(LEFT(Lead,7), LEFT(Date,7)) != 1
           OR Lead is null
        GROUP BY Date
    )

    SELECT *
    FROM CTE_2
    """
).show()
# +----------+---+
# |      Date|SUM|
# +----------+---+
# |2022-07-07| 15|
# |2022-03-07|  5|
# +----------+---+
```